# Store Realm files in Google Drive App Folder?

Tags: android, realm, google-drive-android-api

I am in the early stages of an Android project that will be using a database, hopefully Realm.  I want users to be able to access the same database from multiple Android devices (logged in to the same Google account).  I am considering placing the Realm files in the Google Drive App folder.

I've done some searching, but have found no discussions of this particular configuration.

I have no prior experience with either Realm or the Google Drive API, so I'm concerned that there may be some fatal flaw(s) with this approach.

Any insights/advice appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, Realm only works with local databases. I will be stunned if it supports concurrent access through a Google Drive API.

Comment: That would be an excellent example of a fatal flaw in my proposed approach :).

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you give me any pointers on how I might be able to do it (share database between devices)?  Just some keywords or general ideas would get me going...   Thanks.

Comment: Um, well, the approach that's been used for ~15 years is a Web service, backed by some database.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't Firebase work for you?

Comment: @seanpj, I'm looking in to Firebase now.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Since Realm file format is not designed to handle conflicts when sync with google drive from multi sources, unfortunately using Realm under google drive to sync between multi devices might not be a good idea :(

Comment: @beeender, based on this thread (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913) it seems that the Realm folks are working on a solution for syncing.

At this point I'm still on the fence between using Firebase (with known syncing support), and Realm (with unknown syncing support).  I really like the Realm interface, although I could come to love Firebase, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Since I answered this question, Realm launched the [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/), which is precisely intended for doing this kind of job: Sync an application using a Realm database as the question describes. My previous answer is now obsolete.

---

**Previous answer:** Right now isn't possible to synchronize Realms through devices and keep the app "up to date" everywhere.

There is a similar question in the Github Issues in Realm: [How to synchronize Realm data across multiple iOS/Android devices?](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1208)

From one of the Realm's maintainers:

> Since Realm supports JSON importing, interacting with a Web API is probably the best way to synchronize data between devices. See Realm's Rest APIs docs.

However this is a feature they're working on. You can track the [realm-cocoa Issue #913](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913) expecting changes in this way.

So, I agree with the comments I cited previously and recommend you to sync your applications using the API.

Comment: Yes, I've been following [https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913], thanks.