# Synchronise Realm data between devices

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have been searching around the internet, but without finding a solution.

Is it possible to synchronise the realm data between more devices? Lets take an example, if the user use the application on both iPhone and iPad.

How can i make the data synchronise? I have been looking into CloudKit, but it doesn't seems like it works together with Realm (Correct me if i'm wrong).

Any suggestions? I want the data to be synchronised, and i want a backup of the data - So the user can delete the app, and still get the data down.

Answer (score 2):

Realm now offers two-way synchronization using their own Realm Object Server, as part of the Realm Mobile Platform: https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/

Comment: Yes, i have noticed the new feature. But there is no price plans available. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The Developer Edition is totally free forever for everyone, unless you need Enterprice Edition features.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: The [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) is available (in beta as I edit my answer) so this kind of sync is possible. My previous answer was in an older context, with this technology unavailable.

---

Previous answer: It's not possible. The binary format for the Realm database on the device is not synced on any service like iCloud or Google Drive efficiently.

The long answer can be found in [my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665259/store-realm-files-in-google-drive-app-folder/38646986#38646986).

So, I think the best way for doing so is through an API.

Comment: Damn, you just confirmed what i have been looking into now. Which service do you recommend instead @Orlando? iCloud, if i want it to be iPhone only - And Firebase if i want it to be crossplatform?

Comment: The thing is a copy for Realm won't work for any of these services. The binary format used by the database is not optimal for doing so. I read previously about the Firebase service, but I'm not a real expert on the subject. 
The only thing I can say for sure is that the Realm database cannot (and may not) be synced across devices using a cloud-based sync service like iCloud, Google Drive or even Dropbox. So, why don't you try an API for your service? I think it would be even better.

Comment: Which API would you recommend @Orlando :-)?

Comment: Well, that's a tricky question. The best approach woud be a custom one made by you @Grumme. I don't know if there are services offering this kind of APIs. If you don't have a large experience on server-side apps I recommend you to check out Sails.js, a Node.js framework. There are other concerns. Authentication, for example. Talk to your backend team so you can explore the options :D

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative -> You can try this swift framework to sync Realm database with CloudKit [ice cream](https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Document` folder is synchronise through iCloud

Comment: Can you explain how to use it @bobby :)?

Comment: I never used Realm, but I use CoreData. If I store my database in the folder documents, the content will be shared between iDevices connected to the same iCloud account.
Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Comment: @CZ54 How's about data changing? If one device change the data on CoreData, the other do the same but in different record , how iCloud solve the conflict?

Comment: You can provide methods to perform migration strategy